# Lifetime of a reference passed to async callback

Tags: rust

I have async function to which I am passing async callback. The callback takes a reference as a parameter.

```
use core::future::Future;

async fn foo(bar: &u32) {}

async fn baz<F, Fut>(f: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(&u32) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    let test: u32 = 42;
    f(&test).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    baz(foo).await;
}
```

I am getting the following error if I try to build this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9365ffc09b4a55670b80bfd548ffb65d)):

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     baz(foo).await;
   |     ^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<for<'_> fn(&u32) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {foo} as FnOnce<(&u32,)>>::Output`
              found associated type `<for<'_> fn(&u32) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {foo} as FnOnce<(&u32,)>>::Output`
   = note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the empty lifetime
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:7:24
   |
7  |     F: FnOnce(&u32) -> Fut,
   |                        ^^^
```

I understand that it's not happy about the lifetime of the reference. However, I don't understand why.

- We borrow "test"
- We execute callback f (which is "foo")
- There is no way for baz exits before f is done

So, it looks like there is no way for the borrow to outlive the place where test is declared.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The future returned by `foo()` [has a hidden lifetime](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html#async-lifetimes). The desugared signature is like:

```rust
fn foo<'a>(bar: &'a u32) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'a {
    async move {}
}
```

This is done so the function can hold `bar` across `.await` points. Sadly, what it means is that the function does not fulfill `baz()`'s bounds. The errors are obfuscated because the lifetime is hidden, but this is what the compiler is trying to tell you: the bound should be something like `where F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a u32) -> impl Future<Output = ()> + 'a`, but you cannot express that in current Rust.

For more and potential solutions, see for example:

- [Calling a generic async function with a (mutably) borrowed argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591386/calling-a-generic-async-function-with-a-mutably-borrowed-argument/)
- [Specify Rust closures lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63517250/specify-rust-closures-lifetime)
- [Static future doesn't live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64100406/static-future-doesnt-live-long-enough)
- [Generic for FnOnce that returns a future with a lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316753/generic-for-fnonce-that-returns-a-future-with-a-lifetime)

Comment: I think you can express it through traits, but it's a bit ugly: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/hrtb-on-multiple-generics/34255

Comment: @cdhowie Yes, this is also mentioned (at least) on the first answer I linked. However, I meant cannot express in this way, i.e. there is no syntactic construct that allows you to bind HRTB to two generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Just for solving, you can use `Box` instead of references.