# How to store a pointer to an async method in a container?

Tags: pointers, asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, rust-futures

I have a struct that defines multiple `async` methods, and I'd like to store a pointer of each of them in a `HashMap`, so that I can call any method in one single line, knowing only a key that is given in parameter.

The aim here is to avoid as much as possible to have a huge `match` clause that would inflate more and more as I add new methods to my struct.

Methods all have the same signature:

```rust
async fn handle_xxx(&self, c: Command) -> Result<String, ()>
```

And I'd really like to call them the following way:

```rust
pub async fn execute_command(&mut self, command: Command) -> Result<String, ()> {
    let handler = self.command_callbacks.get(&command);
    let return_message: String = match handler {
        Some(f) => f(self, command).await.unwrap(), // The call is made here.
        None => return Err(()),
    };
    Ok(return_message)
}
```

However, obviously, in order to store something in a `HashMap`, you have to specify its type when declaring the `HashMap`, and that's when the trouble starts.

I tried the most obvious, which is declaring the wrapping function type:

```rust
type CommandExecutionNotWorking = fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> Future<Output = Result<String, ()>>;
```

Which does not work since Future is a trait, and not a type.

I tried to declare a generic type and specify it somewhere below:

```rust
type CommandExecutionNotWorkingEither<Fut> = fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> Fut;
```

But I encounter the same kind of issue since I need to specify the `Future` type, and have a `HashMap` declaration like following:

```rust
let mut command_callbacks: HashMap<
    Command,
    CommandExecutionFn<dyn Future<Output = Result<String, ()>>>,
> = HashMap::new();
```

`impl Future` obviously does not work since we're not in a function signature, `Future` either since it's not a type, and `dyn Future` creates a legitimate type mismatch.

Thus I tried to use `Pin` so that I can manipulate `dyn Future`s, and I ended up with the following signature:

```rust
type CommandExecutionStillNotWorking = fn(
    &CommandExecutor,
    Command,
) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<String, ()>>>>;
```

But I need to manipulate functions that return `Pin<Box<dyn Future<...>>>` and not just `Future`s. So I tried to define a lambda that take an `async` function in parameter and returns a function that wraps the return value of my `async` method in a `Pin<Box<...>>`:

```rust
let wrap = |f| {
    |executor, command| Box::pin(f(&executor, command))
};
```

But the compiler is not happy since it expects me to define the type of `f`, which is what I tried to avoid here, so I'm back to square one.

Thus my question: Do you know if it's actually possible to write the type of an `async` function so that pointers on them can be easily manipulated like any variable or any other function pointer?
Or should I go for another solution that may be less elegant, with a bit of duplication code or a huge `match` structure?

Comment: Where do you use the `wrap()` closure?

Comment: It will be good if you will provide a link to the playground(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Yes, it is possible, but probably more complicated than you imagined.

---

First, closures cannot be generic, and thus you'd need a function:

```rust
fn wrap<Fut>(f: fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> Fut) -> CommandExecution
where
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<String, ()>>
{
    move |executor, command| Box::pin(f(executor, command))
}
```

But then you cannot turn the returned closure into a function pointer because it captures `f`.

Now technically it *should* be possible since we only want to work with function items (that are non-capturing), and their type (unless converted into a function pointer) is zero-sized. So by the type alone we should be able to construct an instance. But doing that requires unsafe code:

```rust
fn wrap<Fut, F>(_f: F) -> CommandExecution
where
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<String, ()>>,
    F: Fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> Fut,
{
    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<F>(), 0, "expected a fn item");
    move |executor, command| {
        // SAFETY: `F` is a ZST (checked above), any (aligned!) pointer, even crafted
        // out of the thin air, is valid for it.
        let f: &F = unsafe { std::ptr::NonNull::dangling().as_ref() };
        Box::pin(f(executor, command))
    }
}
```

(We need `_f` as a parameter because we cannot specify the function type; let inference find it out itself.)

However, are troubles don't end here. They just start.

Now we get the following error:

```rust
error[E0310]: the parameter type `Fut` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:28:9
   |
18 | fn wrap<Fut, F>(_f: F) -> CommandExecution
   |         --- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `Fut: 'static`
...
28 |         Box::pin(f(executor, command))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `Fut` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

Well, it suggests a solution. Let's try...

It compiles! Successfully!!

...until we actually try to make use of it:

```rust
let mut _command_callbacks: Vec<CommandExecution> = vec![
    wrap(CommandExecutor::handle_xxx),
    wrap(CommandExecutor::handle_xxx2),
];
```

(a `HashMap` will have the same effect).

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:34:9
   |
34 |         wrap(CommandExecutor::handle_xxx),
   |         ^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<for<'_> fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> impl Future<Output = Result<String, ()>> {CommandExecutor::handle_xxx} as FnOnce<(&CommandExecutor, Command)>>::Output`
              found associated type `<for<'_> fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> impl Future<Output = Result<String, ()>> {CommandExecutor::handle_xxx} as FnOnce<(&CommandExecutor, Command)>>::Output`
   = note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/lib.rs:21:41
   |
21 |     F: Fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> Fut,
   |                                         ^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:35:9
   |
35 |         wrap(CommandExecutor::handle_xxx2),
   |         ^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<for<'_> fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> impl Future<Output = Result<String, ()>> {CommandExecutor::handle_xxx2} as FnOnce<(&CommandExecutor, Command)>>::Output`
              found associated type `<for<'_> fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> impl Future<Output = Result<String, ()>> {CommandExecutor::handle_xxx2} as FnOnce<(&CommandExecutor, Command)>>::Output`
   = note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/lib.rs:21:41
   |
21 |     F: Fn(&CommandExecutor, Command) -> Fut,
   |                                         ^^^
```

The problem is described in [Lifetime of a reference passed to async callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222940/lifetime-of-a-reference-passed-to-async-callback/). The solution is to use a trait to workaround the problem:

```rust
type CommandExecution = for<'a> fn(
    &'a CommandExecutor,
    Command,
) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<String, ()>> + 'a>>;

trait CommandExecutionAsyncFn<CommandExecutor>:
    Fn(CommandExecutor, Command) -> <Self as CommandExecutionAsyncFn<CommandExecutor>>::Fut
{
    type Fut: Future<Output = Result<String, ()>>;
}

impl<CommandExecutor, F, Fut> CommandExecutionAsyncFn<CommandExecutor> for F
where
    F: Fn(CommandExecutor, Command) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<String, ()>>,
{
    type Fut = Fut;
}

fn wrap<F>(_f: F) -> CommandExecution
where
    F: 'static + for<'a> CommandExecutionAsyncFn<&'a CommandExecutor>,
{
    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<F>(), 0, "expected a fn item");
    move |executor, command| {
        // SAFETY: `F` is a ZST (checked above), any (aligned!) pointer, even crafted
        // out of the thin air, is valid for it.
        let f: &F = unsafe { std::ptr::NonNull::dangling().as_ref() };
        Box::pin(f(executor, command))
    }
}
```

I will not expand on why this thing is needed or how it solves the problem. You can find an explanation in the linked question and the questions linked in it.

And now our code works. Like, truly so.

However, think carefully if you really want all of this stuff: it may be easier to just change the functions to return a boxed future.